# Which of these would be safer/better to run?

Tags: mysql, optimization, distance

I have 451 cities with coordinates. Now I want to calculate the distance between each city and then order some results by that distance. Now I have 2 options:

1. I can run a loop that would calculate distance for every possible combination of cities and storing them into a table, which would result in roughly 200k rows.
2. Or, I can leave the cities without pre-calculating and then, when results are displayed (about 30 per page), and calculate the distance for each city separately.

I don't know which would be better for performance, but I would prefer going for option one, in which case I have another concern: Is there a way I could get out as little rows as possible? Currently, I would count the possibilities as `451^2`, but I think I could divide that by 2, since the distance in case of `City1-City2` is the same as `City2-City1`.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to know which performs better, try it. Come up with sample data and some queries you can run and try them against each of your options. Much better than guessing.

Comment: I'm not trying to guess. I'm just trying to see if any has been proven to work faster/takes less load.

Comment: I understand. Although from the looks of your problem, both should be reasonably quick to implement. However, if the list of cities is static, @Ivan's answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table of cities is more or less static, then you should definitely per-calculate all distances and store them in a separate table. In this case you will have (451^2/2) rows (just make sure thet id of City1 is always lower then id of City2 (or another way round, doesn't really matter)).

Answer (score 0):

Normally the cost of a single MySQL query is quite high and the cost of mathematical operations really low. Especially if the scale of your map is small and the required precision  is low, so you can calculate with a fixed distance between degrees, you will be faster with calculating.

Furthermore you would have a problem if the number of cities rises because of a change in your project and therefore the number of combinations you'd have to store in the DB exceeds the limits.

So you'd probably better off without pre-calculating.

Comment: MySQL doesn't impose artificial limits on table sizes, so the number of combinations wouldn't be an issue. Further, it seems that the OP simply wants to return records based on distance, which would be trivial for a database to do (example: sort by distance ascending, limit 5). Finally, city coordinates don't change on a regular basis, so precalculating distance would actually save processing time in the long run. Precision can be fixed in MySQL. Since the OP is going to be making SQL queries anyway, the cost of a SQL query doesn't really factor in as a significant issue.